# Eclipse Error aapt: error while loading shared libraries:No such file or directory

Tags: eclipse, adt

How to Solve this error ?

```
[2014-05-06 15:21:42 - ahmed] /home/naeem/Downloads/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/build-tools/android-4.4.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: post the output of `dpkg --print-architecture`

Comment: Description Resource Path Location Type
The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolve Unknown Java Problem

Comment: what's your ubuntu system architecture?(32 bit or 64 bit)

Comment: 64 bit system architecture

Answer (score 0):

Try the below commands on terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g
sudo ln -sf /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
```

Now run eclipse. Hope it'll work.

Comment: Not working ...................

Comment: wow, post the output of `ls -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8`

Comment: That error is displayed in Console and This error is In Problems.

Comment: Unparsed aapt error(s)! Check the console for output. appcompat_v7_2  line 1 Android ADT Problem

Comment: WhichOutput you need I cant get it